# how to parse SQL result in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the below SQL query to get the logical filename of my database backup file.

```
$sqlcmd = "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N'E:\backup\OnePDM\DBEmpty.bak'"
& sqlcmd -Q $sqlcmd
```

Now I'm trying to filter only the LogicalName column from the above result using below command. But I'm getting blank value for all rows.

```
& sqlcmd -Q $sqlcmd   | Select-Object -Property LogicalName
```

Is there any way to get this from Powershell command?

Comment: I have had trouble with `sqlcmd` as the data it returns, I have found it to be hard to work with. I switched to `Invoke-sqlcmd` from `sqlserver` powershell module. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: It is generally a bad practice to mix DOS commands with PowerShell. You may consider `Invoke-SqlCmd` from `sqlserver` or `Invoke-DbaQuery` from `dbatools` (I personally recommend `dbatools`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command will not work because since `sqlcmd` is not a Cmdlet. This means `sqlcmd` will only return text, instead of a PowerShell object.

To solve this, you should instead use a Cmdlet from a module like the Microsoft official `sqlserver` or the community made `dbatools`.

## `sqlserver`:

```
# Run this once to get the module if you don't already have it (requires PowerShell Get)
Install-Module sqlserver

# Invoke this every time you begin a new instance (new terminal window or new script)
Import-Module sqlserver

Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance 'yourserver\instance' -Query 'SELECT * FROM whatever' |
    Select-Object -Property ColumnNameHere
```

## `dbatools`:

<sup>*Disclaimer: I have made non-code contributions to `dbatools` in the past but I am not officially affiliated with them*</sup>

```
# Run this once to get the module if you don't already have it (requires PowerShell Get)
Install-Module dbatools

# Invoke this every time you begin a new instance (new terminal window or new script)
Import-Module dbatools

Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance 'yourserver\instance' -Query 'SELECT * FROM whatever' |
    Select-Object -Property ColumnNameHere
```